# HTML Source to Notepad File

Tags: python, html, pywin32, notepad

how can i use python to save a source code i got from a site and then save it as a .html or .txt file
for a project im working on

im using something like this to get the code

```
from PAM30 import PAMIE
import win32com.client 
ie =PAMIE() 
website="http://example.url"
ie.navigate(website)
ie.setTextBox("account","my_user")
ie.setTextBox("pw","my_pass")
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}", 0)
data = ie.outerHTML()

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PAM30 import PAMIE
import win32com.client 
ie =PAMIE() 
website="http://example.url"
ie.navigate(website)
ie.setTextBox("account","my_user")
ie.setTextBox("pw","my_pass")
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}", 0)
data = ie.outerHTML()

with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

saves to 'out.txt'. you can change it, too.

for unicode errors, try `codecs` module.

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("out.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: its giving me this error                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Auth2.py", line 13, in <module>
    f.write(data)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 1727: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>

Comment: if you change `with open("out.txt","w") as f:` to `with open("out.txt","wb"):`, does that fix the unicode error?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i completely understand your question, but here is a solution that I came up with using urllib2.

```
import urllib2

output_file = open('output.txt', 'w') 
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org')
url_html = url.read()

output_file.write(url_html)
output_file.close()
```